# SQL Server : return row from two rows based on the precedence of one over another

Tags: sql-server

I have below table from which I want to return records based on the precedence of the column value.

| col1 | col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | Master |
| 1 | val1 | Distributor |
| 2 | val2 | Master |
| 3 | val3 | Distributor |
| 3 | val3 | Master |

| precedence | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Master |
| 2 | Distributor |

Here I have type **Master** as precedence 1 and type **Distributor** has precedence 2. So, if `Col1` and `Col2` values are repeated for type (`Master` and `Distributor`) then I want to return the row for `Master` as it take precedence over `Distributor`.

**Output**:

The result I want to get is:

| col1 | col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 | Master |
| 2 | val2 | Master |
| 3 | val3 | Master |

Please someone help me write the SQL query for this output.

Comment: Ok, how did you try to do it?

Comment: MySQL and MS SQL (SQL Server) are two different DBMSs. Please select only one and remove wrong tag. If correct DBMS is MySQl then provide precise server version also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `WITH TIES` option in concert with `row_number()`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col3 desc)
```

If two tables

```
Select top 1 with ties A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join  SeqTable  B on A.Col3=B.Type
 Order By row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by B.precedence)
```

Comment: OP have 2 tables... and your query is SQL Server-specific.

Comment: @Akina not 100% sure if it is a second table or demonstrative sequence.  Either way, I will add the second option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INNER JOIN` and analytical function as follows:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from
(select t1.*,
       row_number() over (partition by t1.col1, t1.col2 order by t2.precedence) as rn
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.col3 = t2.precedence) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to optimize, first I do `aggregation with a minimum`, then I merge the table to pull out `type` and then I select `three fields` from all this

[image]

```
SELECT 
 col1,
 col2,
 type
FROM  (
    SELECT  *
    FROM  precedence_table
    INNER JOIN
     (
       SELECT 
         col1,
         col2,
         Min(precedence_table.precedence) AS top
       FROM      `my_table`
       LEFT JOIN `precedence_table`
       ON        my_table.col3 = precedence_table.type
       GROUP BY  my_table.col1, my_table.col2) AS agregated
       HAVING    precedence = agregated.top) AS queried
```